# CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want the priority based sorting for records in a table.

So that I am using CASE WHEN statement in ORDER BY clause. The ORDER BY clause is as below :

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount desc, TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC END, 
CASE WHEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount desc, TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC END,
Case WHEN TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighAlertCount DESC, TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC END,
CASE WHEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount DESC, TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC END,
Case WHEN TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumAlertCount DESC, TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, Patlist.MiddleName ASC END
```

But it gives `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'`

Any solution?

Also I can have:

```
TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 and TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 and
TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0` and TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 and  
TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0
```

at the same time.

Comment: can you show you full query?

Comment: U can write select * From TblList.

Comment: i guess you have the case statement in your query right?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`CASE` is an *expression* - it returns a *single* scalar value (per row). It can't return a complex part of the parse tree of something else, like an `ORDER BY` clause of a `SELECT` statement.

It looks like you just need:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount END desc,
CASE WHEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount END desc, 
Case WHEN TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighAlertCount END DESC,
CASE WHEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount END DESC,
Case WHEN TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumAlertCount END DESC,
TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC
```

Or possibly:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount
   WHEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumAlertCount
END desc,
TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC
```

It's a little tricky to tell which of the above (or something else) is what you're looking for because you've a) not *explained* what actual sort order you're trying to achieve, and b) not supplied any *sample data* and expected results, from which we could attempt to *deduce* the actual sort order you're trying to achieve.

---

This may be the answer we're looking for:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN 5
   WHEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 4
   WHEN TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN 3
   WHEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 2
   WHEN TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN 1
END desc,
CASE
   WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount
   WHEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighCallAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.HighAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumCallAlertCount
   WHEN TblList.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN TblList.MediumAlertCount
END desc,
TblList.LastName ASC, TblList.FirstName ASC, TblList.MiddleName ASC
```

Comment: In this case the sequence is not getting maintained. I want the PinRequestCount<>0 records on the top with ascending sort order of FirstName, LastName and MiddleName. Then HighCallAlertCount records<>0 with ascending sort order count of FirstName, LastName and MiddleName. Then HighAlertCount <>0 with ascending sort order of FirstName, LastName and MiddleName and so on...

Comment: @Dev - will any rows ever have a situation where more than one of those `Count` columns is not equal to 0?

Comment: Also each of the columns for whom I am giving descending sort order can be NOT equal to zero at the same time.

Comment: @Dev - I've added a new guess - like I say, it would be easier if your question actually gave us the information on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok.. Let me give you some sample data with desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I just was not aware of the Edit in answer but the comment. I think your last solution in working.. :) let me test it more. :)

Answer (score 21):

Another simple example from [here..](http://codechef4u.com/post/2015/04/07/order-by-clause-with-case-expressions-case-statement)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN Gender='Male' THEN EmployeeName END Desc,
 CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN Country END ASC
```

Comment: Dead link, Gender should be defined, what if the key comes from the backend, as in `${sort_by} = 'alphabetically' THEN name END ASC`. This gives error in Psql, no such column.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the `WITH` clause :

```
WITH request AS (
    SELECT id
         , CASE
               WHEN a > 100 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
        END AS example
    FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM request
ORDER BY example DESC
```

It also work with `WHERE` clause

Answer (score -5):

```
declare @OrderByCmd  nvarchar(2000)
declare @OrderByName nvarchar(100)
declare @OrderByCity nvarchar(100)
set @OrderByName='Name'    
set @OrderByCity='city'
set @OrderByCmd= 'select * from customer Order By '+@OrderByName+','+@OrderByCity+''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @OrderByCmd
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your answer; by indenting the code by 4 spaces, it is put in `code markdown`. I suggest you add a little explanation to your  answer, that you explain how this code solves the problem. You can [edit] the explanation into your answer. Good luck!