# How to sort multiple column based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
declare @result table (FirstFieldID int,    FirstFieldIDName varchar(100),  SecondFieldID int,  SecondFieldName varchar(100),ObjectID int,  ObjectName varchar(100),    SubSort int ,TotalStudents int)
insert into @result
      select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000125,    'Female',               -1  ,'-1',          -4, 3
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000125,    'Female',               220 ,'Grade 12',    -3, 2
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000125,    'Female',               200 ,'Grade 10',    -3, 1
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000126,    'Male',                 -1  ,'-1',          -4, 5
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000126,    'Male',                 210 ,'Grade 11',    -3, 3
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000126,    'Male',                 220 ,'Grade 12',    -3, 1
union select 1000003,   'Gender',               1000126,    'Male',                 140 ,'Grade 4',     -3, 1
union select 1000021,   'Title I Indicator',    1000380,    'Title I Indicator',    -1,     '-1',       -4, 7
union select 1000021,   'Title I Indicator',    1000380,    'Title I Indicator',    210 ,'Grade 11',    -3, 3
union select 1000021,   'Title I Indicator',    1000380,    'Title I Indicator',    220 ,'Grade 12',    -3, 3
union select 1000021,   'Title I Indicator',    1000380,    'Title I Indicator',    200 ,'Grade 10',    -3, 1
union select 1000010,   'Birth Country',        1000285,    'US',                   -1  ,'-1',          -4, 4
union select 1000010,   'Birth Country',        1000285,    'US',                   210 ,'Grade 11',    -3, 2
union select 1000010,   'Birth Country',        1000285,    'US',                   220 ,'Grade 12',    -3, 2

select * from @result
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
| FirstFieldID | FirstFieldIDName  | SecondFieldID |  SecondFieldName  | ObjectID | ObjectName | SubSort | TotalStudents |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             3 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             2 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |      200 | Grade 10   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             5 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      140 | Grade 4    |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             7 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      200 | Grade 10   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             4 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             2 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             2 |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

At present my data would be like above.
When ObjectID and ObjectName are -1 then the **TotalStudents** will be in descending order with in the group. Otherwise ObjectName is Ascending order.
Expecting the data like below.

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
| FirstFieldID | FirstFieldIDName  | SecondFieldID |  SecondFieldName  | ObjectID | ObjectName | SubSort | TotalStudents |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             7 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      200 | Grade 10   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000021 | Title I Indicator |       1000380 | Title I Indicator |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             5 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      140 | Grade 4    |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000126 | Male              |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             3 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             4 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |      210 | Grade 11   |      -3 |             2 |
|      1000010 | Birth Country     |       1000285 | US                |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             2 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |       -1 | -1         |      -4 |             3 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |      200 | Grade 10   |      -3 |             1 |
|      1000003 | Gender            |       1000125 | Female            |      220 | Grade 12   |      -3 |             2 |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to make ascii tables from your input would be asier to read.

Comment: [`ORDER BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) and [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) should do it. A search on SO for those terms (and SQL) will provide plenty of results.

Comment: Tried many ways, requested to post a query

Comment: Your post didn't include your code or research. Perhaps if you add it someone can help you fix it.

Comment: @HABO, please find it
select * from #ResultTable order by  
case when FirstFieldID = -1 and ObjectID = -1 and SecondFieldID = -1 then TotalStudents end desc,
case when FirstFieldID != -1 and ObjectID = -1 and SecondFieldID != -1 then TotalStudents end desc,
case when FirstFieldID != -1 and ObjectID != -1 then SecondFieldID end asc

Comment: You want to apply the order "with in the group" _[sic]_. What group? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. That should reduce the amount of guesswork, e.g. data types, and simplify creating a functional example, e.g. code to load a table variable with the sample data.

Comment: @HABO, Please find the example script

Answer (score 0):

[CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN ObjectID = -1 AND ObjectName = -1 THEN TotalStudents END DESC
CASE WHEN ObjectID <> -1 AND ObjectName <> -1 THEN ObjectName END ASC
```

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Based on the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql), `ObjectName` will be converted to an `INT` for comparison. This is unlikely to go well for values like 'Grade 11'.

Comment: @HABO, I tried like below, I'm able to get 50% correct.
 select * from #ResultTable order by case when FirstFieldID = -1 and ObjectID = -1 and SecondFieldID = -1 then TotalStudents end desc, case when FirstFieldID != -1 and ObjectID = -1 and SecondFieldID != -1 then TotalStudents end desc, case when FirstFieldID != -1 and ObjectID != -1 then SecondFieldID end asc
It doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the heads up, let me fiddle around

Comment: Aside: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/). Hopefully that isn't the direction in which you are fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking query like below:

```
Select * from #sortData
order by case when objectid =-1 and objectname = '-1' then row_number() over(order by TotalStudents) 
        when objectid <> -1 then row_number() over(order by ObjectName asc) end desc
```

Still not sure what you mean by inside group? How groups needs to be sorted?

Comment: If ObjectID =-1 and ObjectName = -1 then it is a header for underlying ObjectNames with respect to FirstFieldIDName and  SecondFieldName.

Comment: In which sequence?

Comment: If ObjectID =-1 and ObjectName = -1 then **TotalStudents** will be descending and ObjectID !=-1 and ObjectName != -1 for the respective FirstFieldIDName and SecondFieldName then **TotalStudents** will be ascending

Comment: Between ObjectId = -1 has to come first or <> -1 has to come first? Which order?

Comment: , ObjectId = -1 has come first

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and let me know if it works :

```
select * ,row_number() over(partition by flag order by totalstudents desc) 
as rn from(   
          select *, 
          case when objectid=-1 and objectname='-1' then  'Des' else 'Asc' 
          end as flag  
          from result
        )a
   where flag='Des'
   union all
  select * ,row_number() over(partition by flag order by totalstudents) as 
  rn1 from(   
           select *, 
           case when objectid=-1 and objectname='-1' then  'Des' else 'Asc' 
           end as flag  
           from result
         )a
     where flag='Asc'
```

Comment: the ordering here is done only based on studentid .you need to figure out the grouping and order by in the row_number() clause based on your requirements

Comment: Thank you.
But expected result which I posted above is different.
I'm expecting the result same as I posted.