# Want to see query result order as written in query

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query in which I want to show the order of employees as per written in the query.  Query is as follow

```
select * from employeemaster where employeename in
 ('Sachin','Gaurav','Vinay','Shiv','Sandeep','Vaibhav','Prashant')
```

I want to see the query result dislpaying Sachin first then the others and in this case the ID's of the employees is not in sequence, ex. Sachin's ID can be 4 and Vinay's ID can be 1. But as I have written Sachin in first place, then I want to see Sachin starting first in the result.

Comment: The accepted answer here should get you to the goal [CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)

Comment: There is one and only one to order a result set, that is to use an order by clause. There is nothing in the query above to provide this order.

Comment: I don't think the suggested duplicate is the same thing. The OP here wants the results in the same order as the value of the IN clause. I suspect the point is to receive a list of names and return them in the same order. The accepted answer at the duplicate would work but is not dynamic like the OP is searching for here.

Comment: Possibly @SeanLange , however, we're going to need more detail if that is the case. Most importantly, if it is dynamic, is how is that list getting into the query; so that we can then work out how we can also dynamically sort it.

Comment: @Larnu I agree we need more detail. But I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate when the details are so sparse.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CTE with IDs to do the sorting and the filtering with an inner join.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1,'Sachin')
        ,(2,'Gaurav')
        ,(3,'Vinay')
        ,(4,'Shiv')
        ,(5,'Sandeep')
        ,(6,'Vaibhav')
        ,(7,'Prashant')
        ) a (id, [name])
    )
SELECT em.*
FROM employeemaster em
JOIN cte
    ON em.employeename = cte.[name]
ORDER BY cte.id
```

Comment: Pretty much my thoughts exactly. Since I am guessing the OP is passing in the list from somewhere I was thinking a table valued parameter where the table type has an identity column so you can easily order by it.

Comment: i guess i was late to the party! I had the window open a while and didn't see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from employeemaster 
join (values
    ('Sachin',1)
    ,('Gaurav',2)
    ,('Vinay',3)
    ,('Shiv',4)
    ,('Sandeep',5)
    ,('Vaibhav',6)
    ,('Prashant',7))  a(employeename ,_order) on a.employeename = employeemaster.employeename 
order by a.[_order]
```