# Merge two select statement without ordering

Tags: mysql

There is a table TableX (id, user_id, sticky_date, created_at)

Few of them entries having sticky dates.

I am trying to get the result as,

result will contain, all the entries having sticky_date order desc and then all remaining entries order by created_at.

I tried with following query,

```
(SELECT * FROM TableX ORDER BY sticky_expiry_date)
UNION 
( select * from TableX order by created_at desc)
```

But after union created_at is not working as expected. Is there any way to do this stuff in single query.

Comment: you can use `case statement` in `order by` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19487675/2845389

Comment: *But after union created_at is not working as expected*  can you Show sample data, result you get and expected result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TableX ORDER BY sticky_expiry_date, created_at desc`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC18o.png

@jens In this result should be 1,3,2 as order by created_at is wrong in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using computed columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 0 AS position, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sticky_expiry_date) AS odr
    FROM TableX
    UNION     -- UNION ALL ?
    SELECT *, 1, -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)
    FROM TableX
) t
ORDER BY
    position, odr;
```

The idea here is that the `position` alias keeps track of which half of the union should come first.  Then, the `odr` alias tracks the ordering within each half of the union.  The top half uses `sticky_expiry_date` for the `odr` alias, while the second half uses `created_at`.  To deal with the issue of ascending/descending date ordering, we can wrap the date columns in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and order by that quantity (ascending), or by that quantity negated (descending).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC18o.png

Out put is showing as above, where order by created_at is wrong.

Comment: Reload your page, as I have edited my answer a few times.