# Order by ASC or DESC based on parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In the following query I use a `@IsDescOrder` to set the ordering.

I try to specify the `order by` (ie. `ASC` or `DESC`) but I get an error. I can remove the `DESC | ASC` but both options will return the same set because it will return the default ordering:

```
declare @IsDescOrder bit = 0

;with cte as 
(
 select 
 *
 from (
  select *, r = row_number() over (partition by NameId 
  order by 
      case @IsDescOrder 
        when 1 then size_mbps DESC,
        when 0 then size_mbps ASC
      end
  ) 
  from #temp_table 
  ) a 
 where r <= 20
)
select 
* from 
cte
```

I get error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.`.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause

Comment: Asides: Note that a `case` expression has a single data type. If you mix `MyTableId`, perhaps an `Int`, and `DateKey`, perhaps a `Date`, then the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) state that the result will always be a `Date`. Some data types, e.g. `Int`, can be sorted ascending or descending using negation: `case when @Ascending = 1 then FooId else -FooId end`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the right idea but just need to change the way your `CASE` is working a little:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @IsDescOrder = 1 THEN DateKey ELSE '' END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @IsDescOrder = 0 THEN DateKey ELSE '' END ASC
```

This contains two clauses to order by, an descending order clause followed by an ascending one.

When `@IsDescOrder` is 1 then the descending clause is used, otherwise the ascending.  By supplying `ELSE ''`, this ensures that the unwanted order (either `ASC` or `DESC`) is effectively ignored.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by OP, this caused an error if the order column was numeric.  To solve this, replace the empty string (`''`) with `0`:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @IsDescOrder = 1 THEN DateKey ELSE 0 END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @IsDescOrder = 0 THEN DateKey ELSE 0 END ASC
```

This works in the same was as the solution with the empty string, but prevents the type conversion error when using numeric columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've edited the question because I thought that `ORDER BY` would be the same in any query.

Comment: It works in a simple query like the one I posted, but not in the actual query I'm using. I think it has to do with the `ELSE ''`.

Comment: If I only include one `case` then it will return data. Once I add the second `case` statement, I get `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf If the `DateKey` column is numeric, then simply change the `''` to `0` and it should work without issue. So `CASE WHEN ... ELSE 0 END DESC`, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IsDescOrder bit = 1
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 10 i FROM TEST'
SET @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @IsDescOrder=1 THEN ' ORDER BY i DESC' ELSE ' ORDER BY i ASC' END
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
```

What you want is a 'dynamic' sql statement. MSSQL is only doing that is you use 'sp_sqlexec'  (AFAIK)