# ORDER BY with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following in my sql statement

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointName END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'Name' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.Name END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'ParName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN P.ParName  END ASC,
    ...
```

When the @OrderCoumng is 'PointName', I need to sort by CD.PointName AND ALSO CD.PointPerson

I tried to do the following but get an error (incorrect syntax near ASC):

```
CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointName, CD.PointPerson END ASC,
```

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is harder to read and understand, and  SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. Thanks.

Comment: `CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointName END ASC,  CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointPerson END ASC, ...` not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add other `case` expression :

```
 CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointName END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @OrderColumn = 'PointName' AND @Ordertype = 'ASC' THEN CD.PointPerson END ASC
```