# Changing the order in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Output Image, from this i want to change the order

[image: Output Image, from this i want to change the order]`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResourceLoading]
@ResourceId varchar(40),
@Bucketdate varchar(40),
@EndBucketDate varchar(40)

AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @Variable nvarchar(max)='',
 @ResourceTask nvarchar(max)=''

select @Variable += QUOTENAME(BucketDate)+ ',' from BucketMaster 
where BucketDate <= @EndBucketDate and BucketDate >= @Bucketdate
Order by BucketDate; 

 set @Variable = Left(@Variable,len(@Variable)-1);

 set @ResourceTask = 
'select * from 
(select UsedCapacity as value,BucketDate,ResourceId,''UsedCapacity'' As ''Resources'' 
from BucketCapacity inner join BucketMaster 
on BucketCapacity.BucketId=BucketMaster.BucketId
 and ResourceId='''+@ResourceId+''' and BucketDate <= '''+@EndBucketDate+''' and BucketDate >= '''+@BucketDate+'''
union all
select AvailableCapacity as value,BucketDate,ResourceId,''AvailableCapacity'' As ''Resources'' 
from BucketCapacity inner join BucketMaster 
on BucketCapacity.BucketId=BucketMaster.BucketId and ResourceId='''+@ResourceId+'''
 and BucketDate <= '''+@EndBucketDate+''' and BucketDate >= '''+@BucketDate+'''
union all
select  (cast (round (UsedCapacity *1.00 / AvailableCapacity,3) as float )) as value,BucketDate,ResourceId,''ResourceLoad'' As ''Resources'' 
from BucketCapacity  inner join BucketMaster 
on BucketCapacity.BucketId=BucketMaster.BucketId and ResourceId='''+@ResourceId+'''
 and BucketDate <= '''+@EndBucketDate+''' and BucketDate >= '''+@BucketDate+''') t
pivot(
sum(value) for BucketDate in ('+@Variable+')) as pivot_table;'
execute sp_executesql  @ResourceTask


END
```

`

On Executing this code i get 3 records in the column Resources in the order as listed below:

```
Available capacity
Resource Load
used capacity
```

i want to change this to:

```
used capacity
Available capacity
Resource Load
```

can any one help me out with this

Comment: Add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Use a `case` _expression_ in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: i' ve added a image of my result

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression to specify the wanted result-set order:

```
ORDER BY case Resources when 'used capacity' then 1
                        when 'Available capacity' then 2
                        when 'Resource Load' then 3
         end
```

Comment: its showing error , where do i add this code in my code

Comment: At the end of the SELECT that produces the result you want to order.

Comment: still its showing error . if u dont mind can u just show the exact line to copy that

Answer (score 0):

Add Code

```
    Order By (case when Resources ='used capacity' then 1 
                   when Resources ='Available capacity' then 2
                   when Resources ='Resource Load' then 3 END)
```

For Reference Take help from 
[CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)

Comment: Added END, was missing