# Need assistance with if statement in Python code for SQL

Tags: python, sql, if-statement

If I want to filter my table using an if statement how would I go about doing this.

I have an example of what I am wanting to do but not sure how to achieve this.

I want to pull a few values based off of the fact that a customer order is active/inactive.

With my sql column being a bit value type I want to only show "orders" based off of active (column value of 0) orders.

Below is my line of code to pull part numbers, customer number, order numbers:

```py
for row in cur:
    custOrders = CST.OrderLog(row[22], row[23], row[39])
    listofCustOrders.append(custOrders)
return listofcustOrders
```

row22 is my part number
row23 is my cust number
row39 is my cust order number

I need to sort my customer order number based off the active/inactive column (row[2]) which consists of just 0,1,NULL values.

Any ideas, I have not worked with if statements regarding a SQL connection before.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a WHERE-Statement in your SQL and dont get data of inactive customers to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try
`cur.execute('SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE row[2]_column_name = ?',(variable, ))`
You can set variable as 0, 1 or NULL as per your requirement. this 'cur' you can use in for loop too.

Comment: This worked perfectly and of course I had not thought of using this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to approach the ordering in the sql query.

If just a order by 'columnname' isn't what you are looking for, you could use a case statement on the query to order it.

See: [CASE WHEN statement for ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)