# Clever way to reorder records?

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with the following data:

```
VehicleID       Time                    ContextID                   Value
--------------- ----------------------- --------------------------  -----
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:27:14.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:53:38.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:53:47.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:24:20.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:26:46.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:26:55.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:43:53.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:46:01.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:46:09.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 11:02:16.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:39:41.777 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:39:42.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:55:48.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:12.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:12.777 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:32.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:53:57.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:54:10.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
```

As you can see the data is inserted in a timely fashion. But sometimes, the time is incorrect. I need a query to fix it.

If the data was consistent, I would always have a row where the value of ContextID is `SafeProtectDeviceConnected` and the value of Value is `True` followed by a row where value of ContextID `SafeProtectProtectionLevel` whatever the value of the Value column.

I've found out that I have the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) analytics function available to access the previous row values and that I can also put one or more CASE in an [order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause)

Then the correct result after applying the fix query on the previous resultset would be:

```
VehicleID       Time                    ContextID                   Value
--------------- ----------------------- --------------------------  -----
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:27:14.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:53:47.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 07:53:38.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:24:20.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:26:55.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:26:46.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:43:53.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:46:09.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 10:46:01.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 11:02:16.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:39:42.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:39:41.777 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-01 14:55:48.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:12.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:12.777 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:52:32.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:54:10.777 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188 2021-02-02 07:53:57.000 SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
```

Basically If we look at the reordered result set above, specifically the Value column from top to bottom, we should have a `True` value followed by one or more row with a numeric value, then a `False` value

What I've tried so far is using `ORDER BY t.VehiculeID, /*dbo.ContextDetail.Time*/ CASE WHEN t.ContextID='SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND t.Value='True' THEN 1 END, CASE WHEN t.ContextID='SafeProtectProtectionLevel' THEN 2 END, CASE WHEN t.ContextID='SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND t.Value='False' THEN 3 END`

but it gives me (obviously) all `False` rows followed by all `numeric rows` and then the remaining `True` values.

Is this problem a gaps and island one?
What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this: ORDER BY VehicleID, CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Time], 112) AS BIGINT)*10000 + DATEPART(HOUR, [Time])* 100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, [Time]), CASE WHEN ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND [Value] = 'False' THEN 1 WHEN ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND [Value] = 'True' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END

Comment: @Tyron78 That seems to work but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: I added my query as answer and a small explanation - please check. In case of further questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY VehicleID, CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Time], 112) AS BIGINT)*10000 + DATEPART(HOUR, [Time])* 100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, [Time]), CASE WHEN ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND [Value] = 'False' THEN 1 WHEN ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' AND [Value] = 'True' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

The main differences to your approach: first, I verbosed everything smaller than minute from my order by since you mentioned, that time might be faulty. However, as far as I noticed (afterwards) the time seems OK but is not unique - so order by time should do the trick as well. Second, I created one case statement in order to consider context and value instead of one case per column - you want to order by the combination of the two columns, not by every single column separately. So the combination Connected + False receives 1, Connected + True receives 2 and everything else 3.
In your query, you created three cases which return a value or NULL (`CASE... END` without else), so after all you add three values to order by.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the times between the rows that must be grouped do not overlap, then you could use the `Time` column to group the rows and a `case` expression to determine the sorting within a single group. The solution below calculates those new columns in a common table expression for easy selection and sorting.

**Sample data**

```
create table log
(
  VehicleID bigint,
  Time datetime,
  ContextID nvarchar(50),
  Value nvarchar(10)
);

insert into log (VehicleID, Time, ContextID, Value) values
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 07:27:14.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 07:53:38.000', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 07:53:47.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:24:20.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:26:46.000', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:26:55.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:43:53.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:46:01.000', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 10:46:09.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 11:02:16.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 14:39:41.777', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 14:39:42.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-01 14:55:48.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-02 07:52:12.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-02 07:52:12.777', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-02 07:52:32.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'False'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-02 07:53:57.000', 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel', '5'),
(359586015047188, '2021-02-02 07:54:10.777', 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected', 'True');
```

**Solution**

Remark: you can shrink the case expression a bit. It is written out in full here for clarity.

```
with cte as
(
  select l.VehicleID,
         l.Time,
         l.ContextID,
         l.Value,
         (row_number() over(order by l.Time)-1)/3 as GroupNum,
         case
           when l.ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' and l.Value = 'False' then 1
           when l.ContextID = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' and l.Value = 'True'  then 2
           when l.ContextID = 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel'                       then 3
         end as GroupSort
  from log l
)
select cte.VehicleID,
       cte.Time,
       cte.ContextID,
       cte.Value
from cte
order by cte.GroupNum,
         cte.GroupSort;
```

**Result**

```
VehicleID        Time                     ContextID                   Value
---------------  -----------------------  --------------------------  -----
359586015047188  2021-02-01 07:27:14.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-01 07:53:47.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-01 07:53:38.000  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:24:20.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:26:55.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:26:46.000  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:43:53.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:46:09.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-01 10:46:01.000  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188  2021-02-01 11:02:16.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-01 14:39:42.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-01 14:39:41.777  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188  2021-02-01 14:55:48.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-02 07:52:12.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-02 07:52:12.777  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
359586015047188  2021-02-02 07:52:32.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
359586015047188  2021-02-02 07:54:10.777  SafeProtectDeviceConnected  True
359586015047188  2021-02-02 07:53:57.000  SafeProtectProtectionLevel  5
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=73008a52b57ff8f98b3fdbe0aa318893) to see things in action.

Comment: Could you please clarify the choice of the -1 and 3 values used in the GroupNum calculation?

Comment: The `row_number()` function produces `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...` Subtracting one makes it zero based `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` The integer division by three (the number of rows in a group) turns that into `0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...` Without the initial subtraction there would be only 2 zeros and the grouping would be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I have to confirm that I have only 3 rows in a group in the real data.

Comment: I've discovered that I may have an unknown number of 'SafeProtectProtectionLevel' rows. So @Tyron78 answer is a best fit in my case.