# Case expression in Order By processing order for rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, case

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table
(
    ID       INT,
    NAME     VARCHAR(20),
    APPLE    INT,
    ORANGE   INT
);

INSERT INTO demo_table 
VALUES (1, 'John', 45,  7),
       (2, 'Greg', 20, 25),
       (3, 'Alex', 22, 29),
       (4, 'Paul', 50, 55),
       (5,  'Bob', 40, 13);
```

I'm trying to understand the output of the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM demo_table
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN APPLE < ORANGE 
            THEN APPLE
        ELSE ORANGE
    END, 
    name DESC
```

Output:

| ID | NAME | APPLE | ORANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 45 | 7 |
| 5 | Bob | 40 | 13 |
| 2 | Greg | 20 | 25 |
| 3 | Alex | 22 | 29 |
| 4 | Paul | 50 | 55 |

How does the processing work for the order by with a case expression?

The first row of the result makes sense.

I'm not understanding the second row of the output -- shouldn't it be the row with `ID = 2`? (Since apple < Orange clause is satisfied)?

Comment: Try to put the case inside the select, and see the generated values.

Comment: Yes, I can put this inside a select and can see the sorting ok. I am trying to understand how the processing takes place. Thanks

Comment: Once you've selected the case expression, order the records using those values, ascendently. If you have tied values, you tiebrake with `name DESC` instead.

Comment: The `CASE` expression is selecting the smaller of the two values to be used for ordering. In SQL Server 2022 and later, this can be rewritten using the `LEAST()` function, whose meaning is much more apparent: `ORDER BY LEAST(APPLE, ORANGE), name DESC`.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SvEXySf1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're ordering by is this column ASC and this is why ID 5 appears second

```
demo
7
13
20
22
50
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vxfQzaH0) here

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this" column?

Comment: the case when statement creates a column which is not named and not selected, and which I have shown, that is being used to order by.  the order by name doesn't really do anything because you don't have any duplicate data

Comment: So is it right to think: the case stmt in Order by creates a new column, and then the Order by applies to the new virtual column? Is this the case for all expressions? An expression is first calculated and then Order by is applied?

Comment: yes, this is because of placing the case when statement in your order by clause

Comment: btw there's a related question and answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486882/case-when-statement-for-order-by-clause

Comment: what happens when there are multiple case stmts in the Order by? Will they urn into multiple additional columns?

Comment: they won't show up explicitly as columns but they will also all be used in computing in what order your data will be returned, which is the function of the order by clause

Comment: Don't get hung up on columns. A case expression returns a value. That's the critical point.

Answer (score 0):

The CASE expression in the order by evaluates only the first record for chosing the column to order, the select statement order by ORANGE ASC. Next select statement would do the same:

```
SELECT *  
FROM demo_table  
ORDER BY ORANGE,   
         name DESC
```